# AS3 - Attaching webcam video to a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

my task is to code a flash application that lets an user take a snap shot with webcam, attach it to an movieclip and modify the self portrait by adding hair, hats, glasses etc. that are available on menu.

I'm just trying to modify two great scripts: For webcam http://www.riacodes.com/flash/captures-images-from-the-webcam-and-save-them-to-the-desktop/ and for the drag&drop function is use Free Transform Tool http://blog.ryantan.net/2010/08/free-transform-manager/.

I managed to get the webcam working when i used it as a document class. When i changed my code so that the Free Transform Tool code is in document class and the webcam script is in Webcamactions.as file, i can't control the movieclips anymore...the movieclips (such as "imagecanvas" where i attach the video). My Mac's webcam light indicates that the function works, but the video doesn't appear in the movieclip.

DOCUMENT CLASS ---------- TestFTM.as

```
package {
    import Webcamactions;
    import com.ryan.geom.FreeTransformEvent;
    import com.ryan.geom.FreeTransformManager;

    import fl.controls.CheckBox;
    import fl.motion.easing.Circular;
    import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;

    public class TestFTM extends MovieClip {

        public var myVar:Webcamactions = new Webcamactions();

        private static var _instance:TestFTM;

        public static function get instance():TestFTM {
            return _instance;
        }

        public var fts:FreeTransformManager;

        public function TestFTM():void {
            _instance = this;

            // Set up FreeTransformManager
            fts = new FreeTransformManager(false);

            // Register objects
            fts.registerSprite(box, { minW:50, maxW:500 } );

        }
    }
}
```

WEBCAM CLASS ------- Webcamactions.as

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Webcamactions extends MovieClip
    {
        public var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
        public var video:Video = new Video();
        public var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400,480);
        public var bmp:Bitmap;
        public var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
        public var byteArray:ByteArray;
        public var jpg:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();

        public var nowebcam:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        public var capture:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        public var imagecanvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        public var mask_object:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        public function Webcamactions():void {
            nowebcam.visible = false;

            capture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, captureImage);

            if (camera != null)
            {

                camera.setMode(640,480,30,false); // setMode(videoWidth, videoHeight, video fps, favor area)

                video.smoothing = true;
                video.attachCamera(camera);
                video.width = 640;
                video.height = 480;
                video.x = -120;
                video.y = 0;
                imagecanvas.addChild(video);
            }
            else
            {
                nowebcam.visible = true;    
                trace("No Camera Detected");
            }
        }

        public function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            bmd.draw(video);

            while (imagecanvas.numChildren) {
                imagecanvas.removeChildAt (0);
            }

            bmp = new Bitmap(bmd);
            trace(bmp.width);
            trace(bmp.height);
            bmp.width=800;
            bmp.height=960;
            bmp.x = -120;

            imagecanvas.addChild(bmp);
            capture.visible = true;

        }
    }
```

I try to be as clear as possible, i'm really appreciate if somebody could give me some tips how to continue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if it would solve your problem but I'd recommend that you initiate the variables, like camera = Camera.getCamera() and so on, in the constructor function of Webcamactions instead of directly where they are declared. Also, constructor functions are normally not declared as returning void, but left without a return type (they can kind of be regarded as returning an instance of the class, although it is not declared).

Answer (score -1):

I might be being daft here but it doesn't look like you add imagecanvas to the display list within Webcamactions.

Also, it may be a good idea to use Sprites instead on MovieClips when you do not need a timeline.